# Cannot change label text

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Strange bug. I have the following code.

```
private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    statusLabel.Text = "Connecting...";
    statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    serverNameBox.Enabled = false;
    databaseNameBox.Enabled = false;
    connectButton.Enabled = false;
    conn = new SqlConnection("server=" + serverNameBox.Text + ";Trusted_Connection=yes;database=" + databaseNameBox.Text + ";connection timeout=3");
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        statusLabel.Text = "Connection Failed";
        statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed. Error message below:\n" + ex.Message);
        serverNameBox.Enabled = true;
        databaseNameBox.Enabled = true;
        connectButton.Enabled = true;
        return;
    }
    statusLabel.Text = "Connected Successfully";
    statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
    serverNameBox.Enabled = true;
    connectButton.Enabled = true;
    conn.Close();
    UpdateTraders();
    UpdateTransactions();
}
```

"Connected Successfully" and "Connection Failed" both work fine. However the statusLabel is never changed to "Connecting". The default value for statusLabel.Text is "" (nothing).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Because you doing text changing in UI thread and blocking it therefore this problem happens.

You can workaround it using `Application.DoEvents()` after change label text but best way would be using multi threading. Example you can use `BackgroundWorker` class for this purpose.

Comment: Also you can use `DbConnection.OpenAsync()` method (if you using Framework 4.5).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .Net 4.5 or later, you can use `async` to keep the UI flowing.

Change your code like so (note the use of the `async` and `await` keywords):

```
private async void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    statusLabel.Text = "Connecting...";
    statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    serverNameBox.Enabled = false;
    databaseNameBox.Enabled = false;
    connectButton.Enabled = false;
    conn = new SqlConnection("server=" + serverNameBox.Text + ";Trusted_Connection=yes;database=" + databaseNameBox.Text + ";connection timeout=3");
    try
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        statusLabel.Text = "Connection Failed";
        statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed. Error message below:\n" + ex.Message);
        serverNameBox.Enabled = true;
        databaseNameBox.Enabled = true;
        connectButton.Enabled = true;
        return;
    }
    statusLabel.Text = "Connected Successfully";
    statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
    serverNameBox.Enabled = true;
    connectButton.Enabled = true;
    conn.Close();
    UpdateTraders();      // This might need the async treatment too
    UpdateTransactions(); // This might need the async treatment too
}
```

However, this might not be sufficient, depending on what `UpdateTraders()` and `UpdateTransactions()` do. They might need to be made async too, and some of the slow calls converted to `await ...` (assuming they support it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use from this code that sleep system for 5 sec and you can put image loading for this work :

```
System.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

if you using from windows app., put progress bar for this work.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the "Connecting..." text didn't show in UI thread, but it's really work fine.

Because in this method, when after the first line `statusLabel.Text = "Connecting...";` executed, the statuslabel text will be change temporary but didn't show in the Form UI, and then the code continue executing the text of statuslabel will be replace by `statusLabel.Text = "Connection Failed";` when conn failed or `statusLabel.Text = "Connected Successfully";` when conn success.

So in the UI thread, we just see the text change to "Connected Failed" or "Connected Successfully".

In the ***Debugging*** mode, insert the *breakpoint* at `statusLabel.Text = "Connecting...";` line, when press F6 to step over, you can see the statuslabel text changed via the Debug ***Locals*** window.

Hope helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Actually `Label` will be updated to the GUI only after executing `Button.Click`event handler. Put `Thread.Sleep(5000)` between and you will see that label doesn't update

Comment: The fast status change is NOT the reason. When you set a breakpoint, you will see in the dubugger that `statusLabel`.Text' temporarily changed to "Connecting...", however you will never see this value on the UI. As user @Jaex explained, the UI will only be updated after `connectButton_Click()`. The trick is to give the UI a chance to do an Update DURING 'connectButton_Click()'. General options are for example: `await` and `Application.DoEvents()`. And in this special case: `DbConnection.OpenAsync()`.